# Detect unused exported symbols in a a TypeScript/eslint/Webpack based build environment

Tags: typescript, webpack, eslint

I'm using a TypeScript/eslint/Webpack based build environment and consistently detect exported symbols that are not actually used. This typically happens when code is refactored but it is forgotten that a symbol is no longer used anywhere. An unused local function is easily discovered by eslint or TypeScript but is there a way to discover unused exported symbols in a project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ts-prune](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-prune) does the job perfectly